# Copiar ficheros y directorios en Ansible

Tags: centos, ansible

Estoy comenzando a utilizar ansible para desplegar contenedores.
Necesito copiar todos los archivos, directorios, y subdirectorios (que también tienen archivos) que tengo en la carpeta "files" a otro directorio destino.

Entiendo que la sintaxis debería ser así, pero en "loop" no se como definir para que seleccione todo el contenido de "files".

```
- name: copy config files
  copy: 
    src: "{{ item }}"
    dest: /directorio/destino/
  become: true
  loop:
    - ???
```

---

```
$ ls -lh

drwxr-xr-x 2 cmiranda cmiranda 4.0K Sep  9 14:57 defaults
drwxr-xr-x 5 cmiranda cmiranda 4.0K Sep  9 15:34 files
drwxr-xr-x 2 cmiranda cmiranda 4.0K Sep  9 14:57 handlers
drwxr-xr-x 2 cmiranda cmiranda 4.0K Sep  9 14:57 tasks
```

```
$ ls -lh files/

drwxr-xr-x 2 cmiranda cmiranda 4.0K Sep  9 15:32 conf.d
drwxr-xr-x 2 cmiranda cmiranda 4.0K Sep  9 15:32 default.d
-rwxr-xr-x 1 cmiranda cmiranda 1.1K Sep  9 15:32 fastcgi.conf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 cmiranda cmiranda 1.1K Sep  9 15:32 fastcgi.conf.default
-rwxr-xr-x 1 cmiranda cmiranda 1007 Sep  9 15:32 fastcgi_params
-rwxr-xr-x 1 cmiranda cmiranda 1007 Sep  9 15:32 fastcgi_params.default
drwxr-xr-x 4 cmiranda cmiranda 4.0K Sep  9 15:32 html
-rwxr-xr-x 1 cmiranda cmiranda 2.8K Sep  9 15:32 koi-utf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 cmiranda cmiranda 2.2K Sep  9 15:32 koi-win
-rwxr-xr-x 1 cmiranda cmiranda 5.2K Sep  9 15:32 mime.types
-rwxr-xr-x 1 cmiranda cmiranda 5.2K Sep  9 15:32 mime.types.default
-rwxr-xr-x 1 cmiranda cmiranda 2.4K Sep  9 15:32 nginx.conf
-rwxr-xr-x 1 cmiranda cmiranda 2.6K Sep  9 15:32 nginx.conf.default
-rwxr-xr-x 1 cmiranda cmiranda  636 Sep  9 15:32 scgi_params
-rwxr-xr-x 1 cmiranda cmiranda  636 Sep  9 15:32 scgi_params.default
-rwxr-xr-x 1 cmiranda cmiranda  664 Sep  9 15:32 uwsgi_params
-rwxr-xr-x 1 cmiranda cmiranda  664 Sep  9 15:32 uwsgi_params.default
-rwxr-xr-x 1 cmiranda cmiranda 3.6K Sep  9 15:32 win-utf
```

Answer (score 0):

- Te recomiendo utilizar el modulo synchronize, no necesitas hacer ningun loop, si quieres copiar todo simplemente eliges la carpeta origen y destino.
- Por que Synchronize en vez de copy? Copy para unos pocos archivos funciona bien, pero cuando son muchos es muy lento. Synchronize es basicamente el modulo de ansible para hacer RSYNC.

```yml
 - name: SYNCHRONIZE 
   synchronize:
     src: /ruta/a/tu/carpeta/files/
     dest: /directorio/destino/
     delete: yes  # Esto te borra el contenido en destino que no exista en source te recomiendo que mires bien lo que necesitas #
     recursive: yes
   become: yes
```

No se si lo que necesitas es copiar la carpeta files incluida o solo todo el contenido y su subcontenido.
Con el ejemplo que te doy deberias ser capaz de llevarlo acabo.
[Modulo Synchronize](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/posix/synchronize_module.html)